# How to import typescript files in vue3 component?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I just use vue3.
I want to import typescript file in *.vue file like:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Option } from './data.ts'
</script>
```

and in data.ts:

```
type Option={
value: number,
text: string
}

export {
    Option
}
```

I have error:

```
An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './data' instead.
```

Comment: Then why can't you do so? "importing without the (.ts) extension"

Comment: any updates on this issue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `ts` and `js` files are resolved without extension :

```
  import { Option } from './data' //refers to /data.ts
```

if the folder contains one file called `index.js` in its root the folder could be resolved without specifying `index.js`

```
  import store from './store' // store is a folder that contains `index.js`
```

Answer (score 0):

If `"isolatedModules": true` is set in your tsconfig.json, you need `export type { Option }` in your data.ts.